# Want PROLOG to require == matches on already matched variables, = for others

Tags: prolog

I have this code:

```
contradicts(at(X,_),location(X)).
mustContradict(A, B) :- contradicts(A, B).
```

contradicts/2 is meant to say: if X is at somewhere, then X can't itself be a location.
mustContradict/2 is meant to say: succeed if A and B are contradictory.

When I run it to detect that if you're at a location, you can't *be* a location (`mustContradict(at(Thing,Location),location(Thing)).`) -- it succeeds, as it should. On this one, however:

```
mustContradict(at(Thing,Location),location(Location)).
```

it also succeeds, with variable assignment `Thing=Location`.

I could probably mangle a way to make it ensure all variables are identical when trying to match, something like:

```
A=at(Thing,Location),B=location(Location),
contradicts(A,AsContradiction), 
B==AsContradiction.
```

but then it would fail on the first test, trying to verify that a Thing that is "at" something can't be a location.

What I think I want is to be able to distinguish variables that are already assigned to other variables from those that are so far not matched to anything.

Comment: Isn't your example with `==` working for the first test?

Comment: Have you seen `var/1` and `ground/2`?

Comment: It almost sounds like you don't just need traditional Prolog logical programming, but something like [sCASP](https://gitlab.software.imdea.org/ciao-lang/sCASP), see also [this presentation](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~gupta/courses/lp/ICLP-19-autum-school.ppt)? It is available in Ciao and now apparently also SWI-Prolog.

Comment: No, it's got to be PROLOG -- my whole project is PROLOG, and PROLOG works fine for the rest of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to convert all variables to atoms. Only converting those that were shared or repeated meant that the others could bind to inappropriate things (as in the first example), so the behavior didn't change.

Binding them to atoms, as in this code:

```
contradicts(at(X,_),location(X)).

mustContradict(X,Y) :-
    replaceVariablesWithAtoms(X,NewX), replaceVariablesWithAtoms(Y,NewY),
    contradicts(NewX,NewY).
        
replaceVariablesWithAtoms(Term,NewTerm) :-
    Term =.. TermAsList,
    terms_to_atoms(TermAsList,NewTermAsList),
    NewTerm =..NewTermAsList.
    
terms_to_atoms([],[]).
terms_to_atoms([H|T],[NewH|NewT]) :-
    terms_to_atoms(T,NewT),
    term_to_atom(H,NewH).
```

gives the right answer to both queries.

```
?- mustContradict(at(Thing,Location),location(Thing)).
true.

?- mustContradict(at(Thing,Location),location(Location)).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't check your predicates with variables (starting with uppercase), but with terms (starting with lowercase).
   `mustContradict(at(thing,location),location(location)).` fails as it should since `thing` doesn't equal `location`. In your example you use variables that can be assigned anything.
2. I have no idea why you are reassigning `mustContradict(A, B) :- contradicts(A, B).`
3. you can change `contradicts` definition to `contradicts(at(X,Y),location(X)) :- not(X == Y).`
4. I wonder if this is not what you wanted to achieve:

```
at(thing, location).
at(thingLocation, location).
location(location).
location(thingLocation).

contradicts(X) :- at(X,_), location(X).
```

now `contradicts(X).` succeeds with `X = thingLocation`

Comment: Sorry, it's got to be variables. Using terms would prevent the predicates I'm checking for contradictions from applying generally.

Comment: so the 3rd point?

Comment: It's valid in this case. It may not apply generally. For example, contradicts(likes(A,B),unlikeable(B)) should be true whether A == B or not.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier just to write it as you have defined the problem statement:

> I have this code:
>
> ```
> contradicts(at(X,_),location(X)).
>
> mustContradict(A, B) :- contradicts(A, B).
> ```
>
> `contradicts/2` is meant to say: "if `X` is at somewhere, then `X` can't itself be a location."
>
> `mustContradict/2` is meant to say: "succeed if A and B are contradictory."

Assuming that your `at/2` and `location/1` are facts/predicates in your prolog program . . . why not something like this:

```
contradiction(X) :- at(X,_), location(X) .
```

Comment: at/2 and location/1 are functors to be evaluated to see if they are contradictory -- it's important to know that at(X,_) contradicts location(X). Anyway, found an answer using term_to_atoms/2. Thanks.